# Having problems updating values in with array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on code which needs to str_replace colons with spaces. Since i don't know how deep my array will go i have to use array_walk_recursive function. The problem is that str_replace is not taken in to the account (read is not working). Please help me out guys.

This is my code

```
public function removeColonsFromStrings(array $inputs) {
    d($inputs); // some dump function
    array_walk_recursive($inputs, function (&$item, $key) {
        $inputs[$key] = str_replace(':',' ', $item);
    });
    dd($inputs); //dump and die function

    return $inputs;
}
```

and output is following

```
// first d() output
    array(7) {
      ["GivenName"]=>
      string(5) "Me"
      ["FamilyName"]=>
      string(7) "Me"
      ["DisplayName"]=>
      string(19) "[id:: 68]"
      ["CompanyName"]=>
      string(19) "[id:: 68]"
      ["FullyQualifiedName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["PrimaryPhone"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["FreeFormNumber"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["PrimaryEmailAddr"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Address"]=>
        string(24) "my@email.com"
      }
    }

// Second dd() output    
    array(7) {
      ["GivenName"]=>
      string(5) "Me"
      ["FamilyName"]=>
      string(7) "Me"
      ["DisplayName"]=>
      string(19) "[id:: 68]"
      ["CompanyName"]=>
      string(19) "[id:: 68]"
      ["FullyQualifiedName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["PrimaryPhone"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["FreeFormNumber"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["PrimaryEmailAddr"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Address"]=>
        string(24) "my@email.com"
      }
    }
```

So how to properly update values in my array? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending reference, you need to overwrite the old value.

```
array_walk_recursive($inputs, function (&$item, $key) {
  $item = str_replace(':',' ', $item);
});
```

Comment: `$key` should be removed as it is useless, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying leaf-node values by reference (`&`), so you can overwrite values by using the values variable (first parameter in the function call) so there is no need to identify the key as the second variable/parameter in the function call.

Test/Proof: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WBo0r))

```
$inputs = ['a:', 'b:', ['c:'], 'd:'];
array_walk_recursive(
    $inputs,
    function(&$v) {
        $v = str_replace(':', ' ', $v);
    }
);
var_export($inputs);
```

Or with arrow functions from PHP7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3GuLh))

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $inputs,
    fn(&$v) => $v = str_replace(':', ' ', $v)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a ',
  1 => 'b ',
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'c ',
  ),
  3 => 'd ',
)
```

---

In other cases, sometimes `use(&$outputvariable)` is called to permit access to internally generated data, after/outside of the function.  **However, this will not work as intended with `array_walk_recursive()`** because the `key` will be "depth-ignorant".  See this effect as `c` (key=[2][0]) overwrites `a` (key=[0])

Code:

```
$inputs=['a:','b:',['c:'],'d:'];
array_walk_recursive($inputs,function($v,$k)use(&$result){
        $result[$k]=str_replace(':',' ',$v);
    });
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'c ',
  1 => 'b ',
  3 => 'd ',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust `$item` instead of `$inputs[$key]`.